# Xcode 4 analyze RAM usage

Tags: cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, xcode4

Hey how can I analyze my apps memory usage more detailed in Xcode 4 like what things eat memory, as it seems my app takes god damn 40mb memory something is seriously wrong here. Any tools I can analyze my code with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose Product / Profile or CMD-I.  It runs your app in Instruments.  Choose Leaks or Allocations to see how you memory is being used as the app runs.

Comment: There is overall bytes and live bytes, live bytes are the ones which matter right? Like they are alive in the memory?

Comment: Something like that, live bytes are the ones allocated by your program.  Look at the bars to see how much, select a line and open the right window to see the code.  Strongly recommend you take the time to learn Instruments, it helps a lot later.

Comment: It shows like 80mb on the overall bytes and 8mb on the live ones, I can't belive if my app uses 80mb memory.

Comment: If it says 80Mb then its using 80Mb.  8Mb is probably only one of your many allocations of memory that makes up the 80Mb.  Instruments does not lie.

Comment: Now I got it, overall bytes show all the bytes that have been allocated and deallocated. Live bytes seem to show the current amount.